# Using own React npm component - appropriate loader issues

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

I have made a component in my React app that I would like to publish to NPM. It's consists of just one file `index.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class Test extends React.Component {
    //I seem to be getting a specific issue with the lines below
    //Do I need a special loader for these?
    static displayName = 'Test'
    static defaultProps = {
      live: true,
    }
}
```

Originally the component was in a `components` directory of my main app and I include it using:

```
import Test from './components/Test'
```

Since then I have created a new folder (not part of my main app) and added a `package.json` file and the `index.js` file. I have also published it to NPM which worked fine but when I try to use it after installing...

```
npm i -S package-name
import Test from 'package-name'
```

I get an error: **You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type...**

My `package.json` file doesn't have any `dependencies` or `devDependencies` at the moment. Do I need to do something with Webpack and Babel?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to do something with Webpack and Babel?

Most likely. If you are using ES6 syntax in `package-name` then babel needs to transcode that library as well. When I have encountered that error this has always been the case. I suggest updating your Webpack / Babel configuration to include that library.